# Button para inserir Registos na Base de Dados

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

Boas, estou a realizar um projeto para a minha PAP que consiste na criação de uma Base de Dados para uma empresa. No entanto, decidi colocar um **botão para adicionar registos** e quando clico para adicionar, aparece o seguinte erro: **Falha ao converter o valor do parâmetro de Bitmap para Byte[]**. Penso que esteja relacionado com transferir a Imagem selecionada no Formulário para a Base de Dados, e não sei como resolver. Deixo-vos o código da BD; Botão para inserir a Imagem na PictureBox; do Botão para inserir os registos e também a imagem do mesmo erro:

**Base de Dados**

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Utilizador] (
        [IDuser]           INT          NOT NULL,
        [Nome]             VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [DataDeNascimento] DATE         NOT NULL,
        [Idade]            VARCHAR (3)  NOT NULL,
        [Email]            VARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [Telefone]         CHAR (9)     NULL,
        [TelefoneEE]       CHAR (9)     NULL,
        [Imagem]           IMAGE        NULL,
        [Login]            VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [Senha]            VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [Perfil]           VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
        [Localidade]       VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDuser] ASC)
);
```

**Código do Botão para Inserir a Imagem**

```
string Chosen_File = "";
            openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:";
            openFD.Title = "Inserir uma Imagem";
            openFD.FileName = "";
            openFD.Filter = "JPEG Images|*.jpg|GIF Images|*.gif";
            if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");
            }
            else
            {
                Chosen_File = openFD.FileName;
                imagemPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(Chosen_File);
            }
```

**Código do Botão para Adicionar os Registos**

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ocaminhodabasededados");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Utilizador(IDuser, Nome, Localidade, DataDeNascimento, Idade, Email, Login, Senha, Telefone, TelefoneEE, Perfil, Imagem) 
                             values (@IDuser, @Nome, @Localidade, @DatadeNascimento, @Idade, @Email, @Login, @Senha, @Telefone, @TelefoneEE, @Perfil, @Imagem", sql);
            command.Parameters.Add("@IDuser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iDuserTextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nomeTextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Localidade", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = localidadeTextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@DataDeNascimento", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dataDeNascimentoDateTimePicker.Value;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Idade", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idadeTextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailTextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginTextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Senha", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = senhaTextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Telefone", SqlDbType.Char).Value = telefoneTextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TelefoneEE", SqlDbType.Char).Value = telefoneEETextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Imagem", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imagemPictureBox.Image;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Perfil", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = perfilTextBox.Text;
```

**Imagem do Erro**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Você não está convertendo o atributo do componente para o tipo esperado. Pode utilizar a classe `ImageConverter` para isso.

```
var imageBytes = new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(imagemPictureBox.Image, typeof(byte[]));
command.Parameters.Add("@Imagem", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imageBytes;
```